# HDBSCAN Soft clustering - Why everything becomes 1 class?

Tags: python, clustering, unsupervised-learning, hierarchical-clustering, dbscan

**GOAL**

- Using HDBSCAN
- Putting all data points in to a class and leaving behind 0 point as noise (in other words partitioning the data without leaving behind any unallocated data points)

**DONE**

- I have a dataset with 7000 data points and 400 features what are one hot encoded values of cathegorical values (I will shrink the number of features later, currently I am in a preliminary stage)
- I have used normaly HDBSCAN clustering before (but I was left with noise) where 70% of the dataset sparsely groupped in to 50 different groups and 1 group took up 30% of all data points.
- I use soft clustering with HDBSCAN to allocate everything

**PROBLEM**

- Unfortunately this results that for 100% data points the highest probability calss in the soft clustering result vector `soft_clusters` is the single group where previously 30% of the data belonged to before during normal clustering.
- Am I interpreting the soft clustering incorrectly or the results are incorrect?

**CODE**

- I am using the code form the official documentation basically unchanged [HDBSCAN Soft Clustering](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/soft_clustering.html)
- Original Clustering (I added this part to make soft clustering possible `prediction_data=True`)

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import hdbscan

data = npArrayFromPrevious

digits = datasets.load_digits()
projection = TSNE().fit_transform(data)
plt.scatter(*projection.T, **plot_kwds)

'''NOISE CONTAINING CLUSTERING'''
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=10, prediction_data=True).fit(data)
color_palette = sns.color_palette('Paired', 200)
cluster_colors = [color_palette[x] if x >= 0
                  else (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
                  for x in clusterer.labels_]
cluster_member_colors = [sns.desaturate(x, p) for x, p in
                         zip(cluster_colors, clusterer.probabilities_)]
plt.scatter(*projection.T, s=50, linewidth=0, c=cluster_member_colors, alpha=0.25)
```

- Soft Clustering part

```
'''SOFT CLUSTERING
Soft clustering for all the points in the original dataset we. 
RESULT: Each point of the input data is assigned a vector of probabilities of being in a cluster.'''
soft_clusters = hdbscan.all_points_membership_vectors(clusterer) 
color_palette = sns.color_palette('Paired', 1000)
cluster_colors = [color_palette[np.argmax(x)]
                  for x in soft_clusters]
plt.scatter(*projection.T, s=50, linewidth=0, c=cluster_colors, alpha=0.25)
```

Comment: This depends on the data. If I understand the method correctly, there is no reason that this cannot happen. It may just be correct, and it may also be appropriate for the data in case they are homogeneous, which of course I cannot know. Have you tried changing the parameters such as min_cluster_size? There should also be a neighbourhood size parameter (at least there is in standard HDBSCAN). Note that the default parameters are not necessarily appropriate for all datasets.

Comment: Note that the linked "official documentation" doesn't look like a proper documentation - it gives examples but doesn't explain in detail what happens, and neither does it explicitly list all available parameters, so I don't get the impression that all is documented that can be done.